# sql limit current_date timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that I wanna select all rows that have today's timestamp date.

Right now I have to show the latest 10 with the following SQL

```
SELECT col1, col2, time FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

to echo the last 10 entries but I wanna change this so that I can echo all entries that have today's date in the timestamp.

The timestamp adds the timestamp as YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and it's just the date I want it to limit the SQL to not the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use LIKE to find a partial match of any value beginning with the current date, [CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate), with anything (the % wildcard) after it.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp LIKE CONCAT(CURDATE(), '%');`